# Get FrameworkElementFactory from FrameworkElement

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, frameworkelement, frameworkelementfactory

I have a `FrameworkElement`, such as `StackPanel` with children, I need to create a `DataTempltate` whose `VisualTree` property is my `FrameworkElement`. To do this work I need to convert my `FrameworkElement` in the equivalent `FrameworkElementFactory`.

How can I do?

Comment: DataTemplates are just templates. You should not set them explicitly to a specific control because if that template gets used more than once, you'll get an error. That said, you can probably use the [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) class to get a copy of the XAML used in your control and load it into another control

Comment: You can use the [XamlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx#Y600) class to get the XAML for an existing object, then use the [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) to write that to a new object

Comment: Yes, I'll try, if it work write your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use the [XamlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx) and [XamlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) classes to get a copy of the XAML used in your control, and use it to build another control

```
string panelXaml = XamlWriter.Save(myStackPanel);

StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(panelXaml);
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
StackPanel newStackPanel = (StackPanel)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

I think this will only copy the `StackPanel`, so you'll probably have to copy it's children the same way too.

Also per the [Remarks section on MSDN for the FrameworkElementFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory.aspx)

> This class is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates,
>   which are subclasses of `FrameworkTemplate` such as `ControlTemplate` or
>   `DataTemplate`; not all of the template functionality is available when
>   you create a template using this class. The recommended way to
>   programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a
>   memory stream using the `Load` method of the `XamlReader` class.

Comment: `StackPanel newStackPanel = (StackPanel)XamlReader.Parse(panelXaml);` would suffice.

Comment: It turns out that `XamlWriter.Save` saves the whole WPF tree with children. There is one caveat thought: It does not serialize bindings. If you want it to, better check out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27158/XamlWriter-and-Bindings-Serialization